# Get session information of logged-in user

Tags: php, session

I recently started playing with Joomla. So I found out that Joomla has a built-in user creation and log-in system even for the users of the front site. So I was wondering, what is the way to retrieve the details of a user's session, most importantly the username, and any other one, to produce personalized content,e.g. in a php script, when that user makes a request to the site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the details of a logged in user use:

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();
```

The $user variable will contain your needed information from the database, e.g.:

```
$email = $user->email;
```

Use var_dump($user); to see what other fields you have available.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't get to use the classes needed. Is there an easy way to import them? (including import.php failed to solve my problem)

Comment: Well if it's a script outside of Joomla then you probably won't be able to access the user's session. Maybe you should update your question with some more information and code.

Comment: Or another question. When all works, I will accept this too.